# Commutation of SPD matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products, symmetric-matrices

I was reading the paper "A Riemannian framework for tensor computing", written by Pennec, and he defines the space $Sym(n)$ of the positive-definite symmetric $n \times n$ real matrices. There, he defines the square root of $\Sigma \in Sym(n)$ as
$$\Sigma^{1/2} := \{\Lambda \in Sym(n):\Lambda^2 = \Sigma\}.$$

After that, he proves that the square root defined above is unique. For this, he considers $\Lambda_1, \Lambda_2 \in Sym(n)$ two square roots of $\Sigma$ and he says "Then, $\Lambda_1^2 = \Sigma$ and $\Lambda_2^2 = \Sigma$ obviously commute", but it is not so obvious to me. Probably, I'm missing some property of SPD matrices. I will put here the sketch of my reasoning.

I tried two ways. Firstly, I know that $\Lambda_1$ and $\Lambda_2$ commute iif $\Lambda_1\Lambda_2$ is symmetric. But I found some problems to prove that this product is symmetric.

Secondly, I wrote the factorization $(\Lambda_1-\Lambda_2)(\Lambda_1+\Lambda_2) = \Lambda_1\Lambda_2 - \Lambda_2\Lambda_1$, but since $Sym(n)$ is not closed by product, I coudn't continue.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me. I know that it is simple, but I couldn't see the way to prove it.

Comment: Can you diagonalize the matrix?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Lambda$ be a positive definite square root of $\Sigma$. Perform an orthogonal diagonalisation $\Lambda=UDU^T$. Since $UDU^T=(UP)(P^TDP)(UP)^T$ for every permutation matrix $P$, we may always assume that the diagonal elements of $D$ are arranged in descending order. By the definition of $\Lambda$, we have $\Sigma=\Lambda^2=UD^2U^T$. Therefore the diagonal elements of $D^2$ are the eigenvalues of $\Sigma$. It follows that $D^2$ and $D$ are uniquely determined by $\Sigma$.

Let $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\ldots,\sigma_k$ be the distinct eigenvalues of $D^2$ (or equivalently, of $\Sigma$) and $f$ be the [Lagrange interpolation polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) such that $f(\sigma_i)=\sqrt{\sigma_i}$ for each $i$. Then $f$ is uniquely determined by $\Sigma$. By construction, we have $f(D^2)=D$. Therefore $f(\Sigma)=\Lambda$. Hence $\Lambda$ is unique.